# Rewrite SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me with rewriting this code to LINQ?

```
SELECT UP.ProjectId 
FROM UserProjects UP
INNER JOIN Projects P ON UP.ProjectId = P.ProjectId
WHERE P.Status = 1 
GROUP BY  UP.ProjectId 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN UP.UserId = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
The HAVING clause filters out projects related to user with UserId = 1.
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result=(from up in DbContext.UserProjects 
            join p in DbContext.Products on up.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId 
            where p.Status == 1 && up.userid==1
            group up by up.ProjectId into gps
            select gps.FirstOrDefault().ProjectId ).ToList();
```